# Can plurals be translated in Android?

Tags: android

Is there any way to translate plurals in Android?

My app pushes notifications like "The task will expire in X minutes", but i need to do this in a few languages.

Comment: I don't know of a way to have the android framework do this.  I've always used one string resource for a singular (e.g. `notification_string_singular`) and another for plural (e.g. `notification_string_plural`) in each language folder, then programmatically selected one depending whether `x == 1`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Should be no problem. Just define the plurals in language-specific resource folders (e.g., `res/values-es/plurals.xml`). The [Android documentation on plurals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals) shows exactly this kind of thing:

`res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <plurals name="numberOfSongsAvailable">
        <!--
             As a developer, you should always supply "one" and "other"
             strings. Your translators will know which strings are actually
             needed for their language. Always include %d in "one" because
             translators will need to use %d for languages where "one"
             doesn't mean 1 (as explained above).
          -->
        <item quantity="one">%d song found.</item>
        <item quantity="other">%d songs found.</item>
    </plurals>
</resources>
```

`res/values-pl/strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <plurals name="numberOfSongsAvailable">
        <item quantity="one">Znaleziono %d piosenkę.</item>
        <item quantity="few">Znaleziono %d piosenki.</item>
        <item quantity="other">Znaleziono %d piosenek.</item>
    </plurals>
</resources>
```

In code, you would use it like this:

```
int count = getNumberOfsongsAvailable();
Resources res = getResources();
String songsFound = res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.numberOfSongsAvailable, count, count);
```

Comment: I know you can still do it manually, just like you showed in your answer, but why doesn't the Translations Editor in AS display them?